# How does gradle decide the file.encoding JVM system property?

Tags: java, gradle, character-encoding, system-properties

When compiling, running tests, or running a main class, gradle launches java with an explicit `file.encoding`, for example:

```
/usr/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -Duser.country=GB -Duser.language=en
              -Duser.variant -cp … com.foo.MyMainClass
```

How does gradle select this default file encoding (which is ISO-8859-1 for me)?  To switch to UTF-8, I have to add the following to my gradle build script:

```groovy
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }

    tasks.withType(Test) {
        systemProperty 'file.encoding', 'UTF-8'
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
        systemProperty 'file.encoding', 'UTF-8'
    }
}
```

which sets `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`.

### Update #1

[rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768644/rzwitserloot) noted that gradle is likely using the default encoding, which appears to be true.

**PrintCharset.java**

```java
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class PrintCharset {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Default: " + Charset.defaultCharset());
    }
}
```

Then, `javac PrintCharset.java && java PrintCharset` prints

```
Default: ISO-8859-1
```

Interestingly, running from IntelliJ (without gradle) executes:

```
/usr/bin/java -javaagent:… -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath … PrintCharset
```

which, of course, prints `Default: UTF-8`.

### Update #2

Digging a little deeper out of curiosity, the default charset in OpenJDK on linux is [ultimately determined by `nl_langinfo()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/270674ce1b1b8d44bbe92949c3f7db7b7c767cac/src/java.base/unix/native/libjava/java_props_md.c#L279):

**printlang.c**

```c
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
   printf("%s\n", nl_langinfo(CODESET));

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Then, `gcc -o printlang printlang.c && ./printlang` prints `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: There is also an open [issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2270) requesting `UTF-8` as default encoding when starting the deamon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Who knows, but probably Charset.defaultEncoding.

With some more information:

Presumably, it's your platform default. There's a long chain that gradle goes through. First there's the explicit override on the task itself, then there's the ability to override this value for all such tasks (which is what your snippet of gradle does), then there's the `GRADLE_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=....` option which gradle would look at if the task itself doesn't explicitly pick one. The docs more or less end there, but presumably it'll then fall back to whatever `Charset.defaultEncoding()` returns (you can write a 1-liner java app and print that, have a look), and it's simpler for gradle to just retrieve the name of this charset and then apply it everywhere it sets encoding (be it `java -Dfile.encoding` or `javac -encoding`) instead of writing a ton of `if` statements to avoid sending `-Dfile.encoding` or `-encoding` when no explicit encoding was set at all.